# multiple :nth-child statements

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a grid of posts, and I am trying to give each title between h2 tags a different color (green, red, blue - over and over again that pattern).

the html (simplified)is like this:

```
<div class="fusion-posts-container">
       <div>
        <div>                       
             <div>
               <ul>
                 <li>
                   <div>
                     <img>
                       <div>
                          <div>
                            <a></a>
                            <div></div>
                            <a></a>
                            <h4><a></a></h4>
                            <div>
                               <a></a>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
           </div>
        <div class="fusion-post-content-wrapper">
          <div class="fusion-post-content post-content">
             <h2 class="entry-title"><a>THIS TITLE</a></h2>
```

I have tried several approaches and the closest I have gotten to targeting that anchor and change its color is with this:

```
.fusion-posts-container div:nth-child(3n+3) a{
color: #b7e352 !important;/*red*/
}

.fusion-posts-container div:nth-child(3n+1) a{
color: #fb5322 !important;/*green*/
}
.fusion-posts-container div:nth-child(3n+2) a{
color: #1592b0 !important;/*blue*/
```

}

But the only one that works is the red one, if I use them all at the same time it applies the last color to all the titles.

I tried this [CSS: Can't get multiple :nth-child selectors to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20844503/css-cant-get-multiple-nth-child-selectors-to-work) but didn't work, anyone can point me to the right direction?

Comment: show the end of html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this would be your continuation of HTML (which  your question doesn't have) then you can achieve this with `nth-of-type` instead of `nth-child`

Pay attention that instead of `nth-of-type(3n+1)` , for reaching items 1,4,7 and so on, due to your code having a sibling as first `div` with content you can't use the 1st item, so the counting changes then you should count `3n+4`, meaning, it will count from 4 to 7 to 10, and so on.

```css
.fusion-posts-container div:nth-of-type(3n+4) a {
  color: blue
}
.fusion-posts-container div:nth-of-type(3n+3) a {
  color: red
}
.fusion-posts-container div:nth-of-type(3n+2) a {
  color: green
}
```

```html
<div class="fusion-posts-container">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <div>
              <img>
              <div>
                <div>
                  <a></a>
                  <div></div>
                  <a></a>
                  <h4><a></a></h4>
                  <div>
                    <a></a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="fusion-post-content-wrapper">
        <div class="fusion-post-content post-content">
          <h2 class="entry-title"><a>THIS TITLE</a></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="fusion-post-content-wrapper">
        <div class="fusion-post-content post-content">
          <h2 class="entry-title"><a>THIS TITLE</a></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="fusion-post-content-wrapper">
        <div class="fusion-post-content post-content">
          <h2 class="entry-title"><a>THIS TITLE</a></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="fusion-post-content-wrapper">
        <div class="fusion-post-content post-content">
          <h2 class="entry-title"><a>THIS TITLE</a></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="fusion-post-content-wrapper">
        <div class="fusion-post-content post-content">
          <h2 class="entry-title"><a>THIS TITLE</a></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="fusion-post-content-wrapper">
        <div class="fusion-post-content post-content">
          <h2 class="entry-title"><a>THIS TITLE</a></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using (-n+1)

```
.fusion-posts-container div:nth-child(-n + 1) a{color: #b7e352 !important;/*red*/}

.fusion-posts-container div:nth-child(-n + 2) a{color: #fb5322 !important;/*green*/}

.fusion-posts-container div:nth-child(-n + 3) a{color: #1592b0 !important;/*blue*/}
```